# Typescript Recursive Type Aliases and the use of TypeGuards

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I am attempting to remove use of `any` in my code.
I have this:

```
type jsonValue = string | number | boolean | null | Array<jsonValue> | { [key: string]: jsonValue };

const copybookResult: jsonValue = await this.getCopybookCount
```

copybookResult is a relatively complex object that is returned containing properties and also arrays of objects etc.

I then do this where isObject is a simple TypeGuard routine that I call to determine that I truly have an object and I also check that copybookResult.result is an array to allow me to access to its properties and perform the sort.

```
if (Utility.isObject(copybookResult) && 
      Array.isArray(copybookResult.result)
    ) {
      sortedCopybookResult = copybookResult.result.sort((a, b) => (a.includedComponent > b.includedComponent ? 1 : -1)); // ascending
      copybookCount = sortedCopybookResult[0].includedTotal;
    }
```

However Typescript is objecting to the reference within the sort of a.includedComponent and b.includedComponent with

```
"Property 'includedComponent' does not exist on type 'jsonValue'.
Property 'includedComponent' does not exist on type 'string'."
```

I can understand this but I do not see a clear solution.
I could of course specify (a: any , b: any)  but that defeats the objective.

I would welcome any suggestions

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WyQ2ZW) meet your needs?  You need to convince the compiler that `a.includedComponent` exists and is applicable to the `>` operator before you can use it.  If that works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - thanks for the reply. 
Can you please clarify what this line is doing from the first ? onwards


`x && typeof x === "object" && !Array.isArray(x) ? x.includedComponent ?? -Infinity : -Infinity;`

Comment: Do you need such clarification before you can decide whether it meets your needs? I will certainly include an explanation in my answer post.

Comment: I am finding a number of issues as I work through this. For example. Later in my code I want to use .entries() and .length() on my copybookResult.result array and they come back as not existing on type jsonValue - which I can understand but it seems very kludgy to have to hack around so much to convince the compiler that all these exist.

 I am wondering if the use of a recursive type alias is actually worth the effort as I know that these properties will all exist under all circumstances.

Comment:  You know but the compiler doesn't because you haven't told it.  You can either [write the types more accurately](https://tsplay.dev/NlXzQN), or write the checks so the compiler is convinced that you've done your due diligence in checking (as I showed before), or you could just write [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to [bypass the checks](https://tsplay.dev/wRP1Ym).  Or you could use `any`, but you say this "defeats the objective".  What's the "objective"? You either check or you don't check, which do you want to do?

Comment: I have a huge object returned from a REST call.  Within this object there are arrays of objects etc.  Currently I issue the REST call to the mainframe and receive the result into a property defined as `any`.
I do not need to validate the result from the REST api call. That was done when the original data was validated and written to disk.   
I need to get at a few properties within he object plus  a few properties from the array which I access within a 
`for (const[index, copyFile] of csil.result.,entries()`  
I know these properties all exist.

I was trying to remove the use of any.

Comment: Why were you trying to remove the use of `any`?  You've used the terms "kludge" and "hack" to describe the process of runtime validation, and since the object is "huge" I'm guessing you don't want to spend the effort of describing the actual type instead of a union (or am I wrong about that)?  That would make me say "oh you should probably just keep using `any` then", but apparently you want to remove it. Why?